# Reactive UI User Controls in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, reactiveui

when trying to implement the [Reactive UI example](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/compelling-example) in UWP, I hit a snag when I tried to implement the Reactive User Control. I understood that UWP do not allow type parameters in XAML so I followed instructions given on [this documentation page](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui/reactiveusercontrol_1/) and I ended up with the following code :

`NugetDetailView.xaml.cs`

```cs
namespace TutoReactiveUI
{
    internal class NugetDetailsViewBase : ReactiveUserControl<NugetDetailsViewModel> { }

    public sealed partial class NugetDetailsView : NugetDetailsViewBase
    {
        public NugetDetailsView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

`NugetDetailView.xaml`

```xml
<tutoReactiveUI:NugetDetailsViewBase
    xmlns:tutoReactiveUI="using:TutoReactiveUI"
    x:Class="TutoReactiveUI.NugetDetailsView"
        xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
...
</tutoReactiveUI:NugetDetailsViewBase>
```

But I still get the following error:

> The name "NugetDetailViewBase" does not exist in the namespace "using:TutoReactiveUI".

Comment: Try making your base view public

Answer (score 0):

This error appears quite commonly before you actually build the project. Even though the type exists, IntelliSense for XAML does not know it yet, so you get this intermittent false-positive. After you build, the error should disappear and the app should normally launch.

Hopefully this will be improved in future versions of Visual Studio so that the type can be dynamically built in the background and the experience is smoother.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, sadly I tried rebuilding the project but I still get the error

Comment: Is this the only error your are getting? Try to check the Output panel if there are not some other hidden errors that are the actual cause of the build failure

Comment: The only other error I get is "The "CompileXaml" task returned false but did not log an error"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you copy-paste all code and errors, but please keep in mind that your class name is `NugetDetail**s**ViewBase`, but file is `NugetDetail*****ViewBase` (without **s**). Error is saying about `NugetDetail****ViewBase`, so maybe you should align file name or you have error around it.